# Unit testing generating and sending emails with fflib-Apexmocks

Tags: unit-test, fflib, apexmock

I am currently struggling to write a unit test for a method in my domain class, and I'm finding it challenging to understand the logic, especially since I'm new to using the fflib-Apexmocks library. I am looking to test the *generateEmailContractActivationToCustomerSignedBy* method in the domain layer, as well as the *sendEmailContractActivationToCustomerSignedBy()* method in the service layer. Could someone please provide guidance on how to approach testing these methods? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Service Layer method (sends email to contract record signatories, calling methods from selector layer and domain layer):**

```
public void sendEmailContractActivationToCustomerSignedBy(Set<Id> contractIds, Boolean addCompanySignedByToCC) {
    fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance(new List<SObjectType>{ EmailMessage.SObjectType });
    Set<String> extraFields = new Set<String>{'CustomerSigned.Name', 'CustomerSigned.Email', 'CompanySigned.Email'};
    List<Contract> contracts = new ContractsSelector().selectByIdWithExtraFields(contractIds, extraFields);
    IContracts domain = (IContracts) Application.Domain.newInstance(contracts);
    domain.generateEmailContractActivationToCustomerSignedBy(uow, addCompanySignedByToCC);
    try {
        uow.commitWork();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.error(ex.getTypeName() + ' - ' + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.saveLog();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Domain Layer method (generates single email message and registers into the unit of work parameter):**

```
public void generateEmailContractActivationToCustomerSignedBy(fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow, Boolean addCompanySignedByToCC) {
    EmailTemplate temp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate 
                            WHERE DeveloperName = 'Contract_Activation_1709233479135' 
                            WITH SYSTEM_MODE];
    for(Contract contract : getContracts()) {
        if(String.isNotBlank(contract.CustomerSigned.Email)) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToAddresses(new String[] { contract.CustomerSigned.Email });
            if(addCompanySignedByToCC && String.isNotBlank(contract.CompanySigned.Email)) { 
                email.setCcAddresses(new String[] { contract.CompanySigned.Email }); 
            }
            email.setTemplateId(temp.Id);
            email.setTargetObjectId(contract.CustomerSignedId);
            email.setWhatId(contract.Id);
            email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
            uow.registerEmail(email);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried JSON.deserialize approach to be able to place necessary parent object fields into my fake record and seems like it is working for my domain class method:

```
    fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
    fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork uowMock = (fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);
    Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(uowMock);

    String contractJson = '{"Id":"8008d000000yQVeAAM","CompanySignedId":"0058d000007hQuhAAE","CustomerSignedId":"0038d00000sMKEfAAO",' +
    '"CustomerSigned":{"Name":"Test Customer","Email":"customer@test.com"},"CompanySigned":{"Email":"company@test.com"}}';
    Contract contract = (Contract)JSON.deserialize(contractJson, Contract.class);
    
                                                        
    IContracts domain = Contracts.newInstance(new List<Contract>{ contract });
    domain.generateEmailContractActivationToCustomerSignedBy(uowMock, true);
    ((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(uowMock, mocks.atLeastOnce())).registerEmail( (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage) fflib_Match.anyObject());
```